# My App fails for Android 8.0 version Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, android

My App crashes every time for Android 8.0+ version it works fine for other versions any suggestion or help is highly appreciated. Android version less than 8 it works fine it doesn't crash.It looks like `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`: in `SecondaryActivity` in `Oncreate` function.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2830)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2909)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1606)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
 at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6592)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:769)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException:
 at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString (Native Method)
 at android.content.res.StringBlock.get (StringBlock.java:82)
 at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue (AssetManager.java:236)
 at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText (AssetManager.java:164)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getText (Resources.java:334)
 at android.widget.TextView.setText (TextView.java:5523)
 at com.software.abc.bigdata.SecondaryActivity.onCreate (SecondaryActivity.java:89)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6984)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1235)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2783)
```

Not sure how to fix it?

**Code:**

```
 package com.software.abc.bigdata.SecondaryActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import com.facebook.ads.*;
 import com.facebook.ads.AdSize;
 import com.facebook.ads.AdView;

 public class SecondaryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private AdView adView;
private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
Toolbar mToolbar;
TextView textView;
ImageView flag;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondary);
    adView = new AdView(this, "XXXXXXX", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
    //MobileAds.initialize(this, String.valueOf(R.string.banner_ad_unit_id));
    LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "xxx");
    adContainer.addView(adView);

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd();

    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
            // Interstitial displayed callback
        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
            // Interstitial dismissed callback
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            // Ad error callback

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            // Show the ad when it's done loading.
            interstitialAd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            // Ad clicked callback
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
            // Ad impression logged callback
        }
    });

    // For auto play video ads, it's recommended to load the ad
    // at least 30 seconds before it is shown
    interstitialAd.loadAd();

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    flag = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle != null)
    {
        mToolbar.setTitle(bundle.getString("ABCTechnologies"));
        if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.hdfs_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image1));
        } else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.mapreduce_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image2));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.hive_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image3));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.pig_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image4));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.spark_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image5));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.kafka_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image6));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.sqoop_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image7));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.flume_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image8));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.cassandra_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image9));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.hbase_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image10));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.zookeeper_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image11));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.yarn_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image12));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.oozie_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image13));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")){
            textView.setText(R.string.couchdb_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image14));
        }else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Feedback")){
            textView.setText(R.string.feedback_text);
            flag.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(SecondaryActivity.this, R.drawable.image1));
        }

    }

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(bundle.getString("BigdataTechnologies"));
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // handle arrow click here
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish(); // close this activity and return to preview activity (if there is any)
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/** Called when leaving the activity */
@Override
public void onPause() {
   /* if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.pause();
    } */
    super.onPause();
}

/** Called when returning to the activity */
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   /* if (mAdView != null) {
        mAdView.resume();
    } */
}

/** Called before the activity is destroyed */
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (interstitialAd != null) {
        interstitialAd.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Thanks and Regards
Bhavesh

Comment: `onCreate (SecondaryActivity.java:89)`? Point out which line it is .

Comment: I am new to Java but the line which it points to in eclipse is if(bundle != null)

Comment: Thats not possible Run your code again and update the line which is causing issue in question ,

Comment: Sorry the correct line seems to be else if (mToolbar.getTitle().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("XXXXXX")){